# SQL statement - join based on date

Tags: sql-server, date

I need to write a statement joining two tables based on dates.

Table 1 contains time recording entries.

```
+----+-----------+--------+---------------+  
| ID | Date      | UserID | DESC          |  
+----+-----------+--------+---------------+  
| 1  | 1.10.2010 | 5      | did some work |  
| 2  | 1.10.2011 | 5      | did more work |  
| 3  | 1.10.2012 | 4      | me too        |  
| 4  | 1.11.2012 | 4      | me too        |  
+----+-----------+--------+---------------+
```

Table 2 contains the position of each user in the company. The ValidFrom date is the date at which the user has been or will be promoted.

```
+----+-----------+--------+------------+
| ID | ValidFrom | UserID | Pos        |
+----+-----------+--------+------------+
| 1  | 1.10.2009 | 5      | PM         |
| 2  | 1.5.2010  | 5      | Senior PM  |
| 3  | 1.10.2010 | 4      | Consultant |
+----+-----------+--------+------------+
```

I need a query which outputs table one with one added column which is the position of the user at the time the entry has been made. (the Date column)
All date fileds are of type date.

I hope someone can help. I tried a lot but don't get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT ID, [Date], UserID, [DESC], x.Pos
FROM table1 AS t1
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 Pos
  FROM table2 AS t2
  WHERE t2.UserID = t1.UserID AND t2.ValidFrom <= t1.[Date]
  ORDER BY t2.ValidFrom DESC) AS x(Pos)
```

For every row of `table1` `OUTER APPLY` operation fetches all `table2` rows of the same user that have a `ValidFrom` date that is older or the same as `[Date]`. These rows are sorted in descending order and *the most recent* of these is finally returned.

Note: If no match is found by the `OUTER APPLY` sub-query then a `NULL` value is returned, meaning that no valid position exists in `table2` for the corresponding record in `table1`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3df4d)

Answer (score 4):

Try this using a subselect in the where clause:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/355a9/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeRecord
(
  ID INT,
  [Date] Date,
  UserID INT,
  Description VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO TimeRecord
VALUES (1,'2010-01-10',5,'did some work'),
        (2, '2011-01-10',5,'did more work'),
        (3, '2012-01-10', 4, 'me too'),
        (4, '2012-11-01',4,'me too') 

CREATE TABLE UserPosition
(
  ID Int,
  ValidFrom Date,
  UserId INT,
  Pos VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO UserPosition
VALUES (1, '2009-01-10', 5, 'PM'),
      (2, '2010-05-01', 5, 'Senior PM'),
      (3, '2010-01-10', 4, 'Consultant ')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TR.ID,
       TR.[Date],
       TR.UserId,
       TR.Description,
       UP.Pos
FROM TimeRecord TR
INNER JOIN UserPosition UP
  ON UP.UserId = TR.UserId 
WHERE UP.ValidFrom = (SELECT MAX(ValidFrom) 
                      FROM UserPosition UP2 
                      WHERE UP2.UserId = UP.UserID AND
                            UP2.ValidFrom <= TR.[Date])
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/355a9/1/0)**:

```
| ID |       Date | UserId |   Description |         Pos |
|----|------------|--------|---------------|-------------|
|  1 | 2010-01-10 |      5 | did some work |          PM |
|  2 | 2011-01-10 |      5 | did more work |   Senior PM |
|  3 | 2012-01-10 |      4 |        me too | Consultant  |
|  4 | 2012-11-01 |      4 |        me too | Consultant  |
```

Answer (score 1):

This works by using a rank function and subquery. I tested it with some sample data.

```
   select sub.ID,sub.Date,sub.UserID,sub.Description,sub.Position 
from(
    select rank() over(partition by t1.userID order by t2.validfrom desc) 
    as 'rank', t1.ID as'ID',t1.Date as'Date',t1.UserID as'UserID',t1.Descr   
    as'Description',t2.pos as'Position', t2.validfrom as 'validfrom' 

    from temployee t1 inner join jobs t2 on -- replace join tables with your own table names
    t1.UserID=t2.UserID 
    ) as sub
where rank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query would work

```
select t1.*,t2.pos from Table1 t1 left outer join Table2 t2 on 
t1.Date=t2.Date and t1.UserID=t2.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks. But the dates in both tables don't match. I need to take the entry from table 2 where t1.UserID=t2.UserID and MAX(t2.ValidFrom) and t2.ValidFrom<= t1.Date and t2.ValidFrom<= GETDATE().